# RabbitMQ Generic Server terminating

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to connect 1000 clients to RabbitMQ. Everything works fine until a 100 connections but as soon as I try going to 1000 connections I start to get errors. One of the errors in the log file is as follows.

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Nov-2017::11:28:17 ===
** Generic server <0.17692.0> terminating
** Last message in was pre_hibernate
** When Server state == {q,
                         {amqqueue,
                          {resource,<<"/">>,queue,
                           <<"stomp-subscription-52t0wLkuhIW93v2ReUC3ug">>},
                          false,true,none,[],<0.17692.0>,[],[],[],undefined,
                          [],[],live,0},
                         none,true,rabbit_priority_queue,
                         {passthrough,rabbit_variable_queue,
                          {vqstate,
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {delta,undefined,0,0,undefined},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           {0,{[],[]}},
                           0,
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {qistate,
                            "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-172-31-27-0/queues/3RBJZVANXRGKSPW9Y4JDQNMPL",
                            {{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                              {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                               []},
                              {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                []}}},
                             []},
                            undefined,0,32768,
                            #Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.2.31077630>,
                            #Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.3.31077630>,
                            {0,nil},
                            {0,nil},
                            [],[]},
                           {undefined,
                            {client_msstate,msg_store_transient,
                             <<238,57,96,242,159,89,24,222,239,145,47,13,81,62,                               55,43>>,
                             {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                              {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                               []},
                              {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                []}}},
                             {state,5963862,
                              "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-172-31-27-0/msg_store_transient"},
                             rabbit_msg_store_ets_index,
                             "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-172-31-27-0/msg_store_transient",
                             <0.311.0>,6029399,5898325,6094936,6160473,
                             {4000,800}}},
                           false,0,4096,0,0,0,0,0,0,infinity,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                           {rates,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1511848696347412},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           {0,nil},
                           0,0,0,0,4096,default,0}},
                         {state,
                          {queue,
                           [{<0.17572.0>,{consumer,<<"T_0">>,false,0,[]}}],
                           [],1},
                          {active,1511848694492143,1.0}},
                         undefined,undefined,
                         {erlang,#Ref<0.0.0.176942>},
                         undefined,
                         {state,none,5000,undefined},
                         {0,nil},
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,
                         {state,
                          {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                           {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                           {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                             []}}},
                          delegate},
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,1,0,running}
** Reason for termination ==
** {{emfile,[{erlang,open_port,
                     [{spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd 2>&1"},[stream]],
                     []},
             {os,start_port_srv_handle,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,278}]},             {os,start_port_srv_loop,0,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,294}]}]},
    {gen_server2,call,
                 [rabbit_memory_monitor,
                  {report_ram_duration,<0.17692.0>,infinity},
                  infinity]}}
```

Also, for some reason I keep getting the following warning

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 28-Nov-2017::11:28:17 ===
Memory monitor process not yet started: {gen_server,call,
                                         [vm_memory_monitor,
                                          get_cached_process_memory_and_limit,
                                          infinity]}
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

FYI, the only change in config that I do is following:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'file_handle_cache:set_limit(65000).'
```

Comment: I suspect your problem has something to do with the system running out of file handles or some other limited resource (perhaps memory). Can you get some of these parameters out and put them in your question?

Comment: Additionally, have a look at this page to see if there are any other parameters. We really don't have enough details to be able to offer anything but a guess as to what could be wrong. https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html
I also recommend asking on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=rabbitmq)

Comment: The problem was that while the limit for number of file descriptors had been raised using rabbitmqctl it was still not changed at the OS level. So it wasn't able to create the necessary connections.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. So are you saying this issue is closed? Perhaps you could post a quick summary of what you did as an answer, including how many file descriptors had been configured, and any details about your host configuration (RMQ server version, Linux flavor/version, etc.)

Comment: I think it could not open new port. According to the Erlang efficiency guide:
The maximum number of simultaneously open Erlang ports is often by default 16,384. This limit can be configured at startup. For more information, see the +Q command-line flag in the erl(1) manual page in ERTS

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that while the max number of open file descriptors was increased through rabbitmqctl, the limit at the OS level was still not bumped up. Hence the new connections could not be opened.

The error message is very clear if the "file_handle_cache" limit of RabbitMQ gets hit. In that case, in the logs it says that the alarm has been set for the max number of open file descriptors and no new connections will be taken until the alarm clears.

But if the OS limit gets hit, then the error is not clear and hence it was difficult to find out what was the issue.

Also, the RabbitMQ Web Console shows the correct number of available sockets and file handlers, considering both the RabbitMQ config and the OS limits. That is very helpful to figure out the issue.